# Target action set for a custom button is not called

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, selector, target

I have this `UIViewController` subclass:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    let backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
       let backgroundImage = UIImage(named:"backgroundImg")
       let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image:backgroundImage)
       backgroundImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       backgroundImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
       return backgroundImageView
    }()

    let containerView: UIView = {
       let view = UIView()
       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
       return view
    }()

    let customButton: MyCustomButton = {
       let customButton = MyCustomButton()
       customButton.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 50)
       return customButton
    }()

    // More properties and methods

    override func loadView() {
       self.view = UIView()
       self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

       self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
       backgroundImageView.addSubview(containerView)

       self.view.addSubview(customButton)
       self.customButton.addTarget(self, action:"navigate", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

       view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }

    override func updateViewConstraints() {

       backgroundImageView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()

       containerView.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: (navigationController?.navigationBar)!, withOffset: 0)
       containerView.autoPinEdge(.Left, toEdge: .Left, ofView: backgroundImageView, withOffset: 0)
       containerView.autoPinEdge(.Right, toEdge: .Right, ofView: self.backgroundImageView, withOffset: 0)
       containerView.autoPinEdge(.Bottom, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: self.backgroundImageView, withOffset: 0) code here

       self.customButton.autoPinEdge(.Left, toEdge: .Left, ofView: self.containerView, withOffset: 10)
       self.customButton.autoPinEdge(.Right, toEdge: .Right, ofView: self.containerView, withOffset: -10)
       self.customButton.autoPinEdge(.Bottom, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: self.containerView, withOffset: -10)

       super.updateViewConstraints()
   }

   func navigate() {
       let nextVC = NextViewController()
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
   }

}
```

I'm using [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout) framework to arrange subviews. The custom button is correctly displayed, but when I tap on it the `navigate` method is not called, and I don't understand why... could someone give me a hint?

Thanks

**EDIT**: added the view hierarchy in the code snippet. It seems that the custom button is not receiving touch events this way, why?

Comment: Try to use `Selector("navigate")` instead of just `"navigate"`.

Comment: Try action:"navigate:"

Comment: Thank you both. It looks like the problem is not actually in the `addTarget` method but in my views hierarchy (and I neither understand why), so I'm going to update my question to show the actual view hierarchy I have

Comment: Make sure all the views above the button have `allowsUserInteraction` set to true

Comment: @Paulw11 That worked, thanks